# Can tensorflow Session.run() return memory address to variable rather than a copy

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, session, copy

I'm using TensorFlow to train a deep neural network. Python interacts with TensorFlow via `Session`, which outputs the results.

In my case, I want to return the weights of my network, use them to process my data externally (i.e. outside tensorflow), and then pass the weights back to tensorflow to update them.

Extracting the weights from the model can be done using a Session:

```
DNN # a class which contains my tensorflow DNN model
W_fc = sess.run(DNN.W_fc)
```

And passing them back can be done simlarly

```
sess.run(..., feed_dict = {DNN.W_fc: W_fc})
```

My guess is that `sess.run()` makes a copy of the internal tensorflow weights variable which it returns to python.

my QUESTION:

Is there any way to make `sess.run()` return the memory address to the internal tensorflow variable instead? This can save me quite some memory.